# Hash function with Go generics

Tags: go

I'm learning Go generics introduced in version 1.18 and want to implement a hash function that returns a hash value of any hashable object. Ideally it would work similarly as the `std::hash` template in C++, like `std::hash<type>{}(x)`.

I already defined a Hashable interface:

```
type Hashable interface {int | string}
```

However, I don't know how to proceed next. Since I want different behaviors for different types such as int and string, and I want the implementation to be determined in compile-time to avoid any runtime type-checking overhead. Is there any way I can do this using Go generics just like in C++ STL?

EDIT:
I benchmarked the solution posted by @Para, and I found it less efficient than a type-switch implementation, even when type inference is disabled. I guess there is some runtime overhead calling generic functions in Go. Here is the code for benchmark.

hash.go

```
package hash

import (
    "hash/fnv"
)

type Hashable interface {
    int | string
}

func Hash(x any) int {
    switch v := x.(type) {
    case int:
        return v
    case string:
        return stringHash(v)
    default:
        panic("hash function of this type not implemented")
    }
}

func intHash(x int) int {
    return x
}

func stringHash(x string) int {
    h := fnv.New32a()
    h.Write([]byte(x))
    return int(h.Sum32())
}

type Hint int
type Hstring string
type Hasher interface {
    Hash() int
}

func (x Hint) Hash() int {
    return int(x)
}

func (x Hstring) Hash() int {
    h := fnv.New32a()
    h.Write([]byte(x))
    return int(h.Sum32())
}

type HashableAlias interface {
    Hint | Hstring
    Hasher
}

func GetHash[T HashableAlias](h T) int {
    return h.Hash()
}
```

hash_test.go

```
package hash

import (
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkHashStringTypeSwitch(b *testing.B) {
    s := "func (this *LRUCache) Get(key int) int {"
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Hash(s)
    }
}

func BenchmarkHashString(b *testing.B) {
    s := "func (this *LRUCache) Get(key int) int {"
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        stringHash(s)
    }
}

func BenchmarkHashIntTypeSwitch(b *testing.B) {
    n := 123456
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Hash(n)
    }
}

func BenchmarkHashInt(b *testing.B) {
    n := 123456
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        intHash(n)
    }
}

func BenchmarkGetHashInt(b *testing.B) {
    n := 123456
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        GetHash(Hint(n))
    }
}

func BenchmarkGetHashIntHalfConvert(b *testing.B) {
    var n Hint = 123456
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        GetHash(n)
    }
}

func BenchmarkGetHashIntMethod(b *testing.B) {
    n := 123456
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Hint(n).Hash()
    }
}

func BenchmarkGetHashIntNoInfer(b *testing.B) {
    n := 123456
    f := GetHash[Hint]
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        f(Hint(n))
    }
}

func BenchmarkGetHashString(b *testing.B) {
    s := "func (this *LRUCache) Get(key int) int {"
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        GetHash(Hstring(s))
    }
}
```

benchmark output (go version go1.19.4 darwin/arm64)

```
BenchmarkExtendibleHashTable-10          9066850               148.8 ns/op
BenchmarkHashStringTypeSwitch-10        26299448                43.56 ns/op
BenchmarkHashString-10                  25259280                43.05 ns/op
BenchmarkHashIntTypeSwitch-10           1000000000               0.6236 ns/op
BenchmarkHashInt-10                     1000000000               0.3114 ns/op
BenchmarkGetHashInt-10                  552110401                2.109 ns/op
BenchmarkGetHashIntHalfConvert-10       576661430                2.125 ns/op
BenchmarkGetHashIntMethod-10            1000000000               0.3118 ns/op
BenchmarkGetHashIntNoInfer-10           560186821                2.119 ns/op
BenchmarkGetHashString-10               26585163                44.29 ns/op
```

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type hint int
type hstring string
type Hasher interface {
    Hash() []byte
}

func (h hint) Hash() []byte {
    return []byte("hint")
}

func (h hstring) Hash() []byte {
    return []byte("hstring")
}

type Hashable interface {
    hint | hstring
    Hasher
}

func GetHash[T Hashable](h T) []byte {
    return h.Hash()
}
func main() {
    var a hint = 1
    var b hstring = "111111"
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", GetHash(a))
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", GetHash(b))

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean implementation. I benchmarked it and found some runtime overhead. Idk why...

Comment: I think I understand why, that is Go does not support monomorphization. See this post: https://planetscale.com/blog/generics-can-make-your-go-code-slower and this https://research.swtch.com/interfaces

Comment: Why would you have a generic function to only call an interface method, when you can just call the interface method from the `Hasher` interface?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I'm implementing a template map container woking like map[K]V, which ideally calls a generic hashing function somewhere in it :)

Comment: Why is that "ideal" in your opinion?

Comment: Because I already know the key is of type K, so the hash function can be instantiated together with my map container.